# describe request xml body based on xsd in swagger

Tags: xml, xsd, swagger

I am trying to describe some rest endpoints with the help of swagger. For a post request, we need to accept xml responses based on a specific xsd schema. I was wondering if it is possible in swagger to reference the specific schema to describe the request body without creating the objects in the models section.

Comment: I did do a quick Google search, but could not find any evidence that this is possible. RAML can refer to an XSD, but I don't think Swagger/OpenAPI can.

Comment: Hi @kimbert, I also could not find anything, it seems that i have to create some objects in the yaml file that they are the same as the xsd describes, I also could not find anything else unfortunately